# Finding approximate analytic solution of transcendental function, possible Lambert function?

Tags: lambert-w, transcendental-equations

My original problem is $$g(r)=\ln(1+r)-a\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}}$$
where $r\geq0$ is a variable, $a\geq0$ is a constant. And I'm trying to find the root where $g(r)=0$. This is an transcendental equation, maybe it's hard to find the analytic solution, so I'm trying to find the approximate analytic solution.

**What I have tried:**

Letting $x=\ln(1+r)\geq0$, we can obtain$$x-a\sqrt{1-e^{-2x}}=0$$ $$x^2=a^2(1-e^{-2x})$$
$$e^{-2x}=1-\frac{1}{a^2}x^2=\frac{1}{a^2}(x^2-a^2)$$
then, letting $f(x)=e^{-2x}+\frac{1}{a^{2}}(x+a)(x-a)$, where $a\geq0$, $x\geq0$.

I have tried to find the root using Lambert W function, but I don't know how to transform the equation to the form $xe^x=c$.

Can I find the approximate analytic solution where $f(x)=0$ using Lambert W function? Or is there any other way to solve $g(r)=0$?

**Now we can obtain better approximate analytic solution when $a\geq2$, but the approximation error of $g(r)$ is big than $10^{−2}$ for $2\geq a \geq0$. How to further obtain a better approximate analytic solution for $2\geq a \geq0$?**

Comment: For $a>1$, say, $r \approx e^a  - 1 + \frac{a}{2}e^{ - a} $ is a good first approximation to the zero. You may use, for example, Newton's method to improve on this approximation.

Comment: Hello, sir. How can I obtain the approximate solution you posed?

Comment: Sorry, it is $r \approx e^a-1-\frac{a}{2} e^{-a}$. First, for large $r$, the equation is $\log(1+r) \approx a$. Hence $r \approx e^a-1$. Now we look for the root in the form $
r = e^a  - 1 + f(a)$ where $f(a)$ is much smaller than $e^a$. Using Taylor approximations $$
0 = \log (e^a  + f(a)) - a\sqrt {1 - \frac{1}{{(e^a  + f(a))^2 }}}  \approx f(a)e^{ - a}  + \frac{a}{2}e^{ - 2a} ,
$$ i.e., $f(a) \approx -\frac{a}{2} e^{-a}$.

Comment: Hello sir, bother you again. I don't konw how to use Taylor series to approximate $\ln(e^a+f(a))$ and $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{(e^a+f(a))^2}}$. Could you explain it in detail?

Comment: $$\log (e^a  + f(a)) = a + \log (1 + f(a)e^{ - a} ) \approx a + f(a)e^{ - a} $$ and $$
\sqrt {1 - \frac{1}{{(e^a  + f(a))^2 }}}  \approx 1 - \frac{1}{{2(e^a  + f(a))^2 }} \approx 1 - \frac{1}{{2e^{2a} }} = 1 - \frac{1}{2}e^{ - 2a} .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider instead that you look for the zero of function
$$f(r)=\frac{(r+1) \log (r+1)}{\sqrt{r (r+2)}}-a$$

If $a$ is large, make a series expansion
$$\frac{(r+1) \log (r+1)}{\sqrt{r (r+2)}}=\log (r)+\frac{1}{r}+\frac{\log (r)-1}{2 r^2}+\frac{5-6\log
   (r)}{6r^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{r^4}\right)$$ So, a first approximation is given by
$$\log (r)+\frac{1}{r}=a \implies r_0=-\frac{1}{W\left(-e^{-a}\right)}$$ and here is Lambert function.

Using then next term of the expansion would give
$$\log(r_1)=\frac{2 a r_0^2-2 r_0+1}{2 r_0^2+1}\implies r_1=\exp\left(\frac{2 a r_0^2-2 r_0+1}{2 r_0^2+1} \right)$$

A few numbers for illustration

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
a & r_0 & r_1 & \text{exact} \\
  1.00 & 1.00000 & 1.39561 &  1.50068 \\
 1.25 & 2.22825 & 2.26915 &  2.28989 \\
 1.50 & 3.31445 & 3.28596 &  3.30121 \\
 1.75 & 4.63863 & 4.58267 &  4.59469 \\
 2.00 & 6.30540 & 6.23985 &  6.24911 \\
 2.25 & 8.42598 & 8.35958 &  8.36650 \\
 2.50 & 11.1362 & 11.0733 &  11.0784 \\
 2.75 & 14.6076 & 14.5503 &  14.5539 \\
 3.00 & 19.0588 & 19.0079 &  19.0104 \\
 3.25 & 24.7699 & 24.7254 &  24.7271 \\
 3.50 & 32.0997 & 32.0613 &  32.0625 \\
 3.75 & 41.5089 & 41.4761 &  41.4769 \\
 4.00 & 53.5888 & 53.5610 &  53.5615
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If you notice that $r(r+2) \sim (r+1)^2$, you have the easy estimate $r_0=e^a-1$  and the first iterate of Newton method is
$$r_1=e^a-1-\frac{a \left(e^{2 a}-1\right) \left(e^a-\sqrt{e^{2 a}-1}\right)}{e^{2 a}-a-1}$$  which is quite accurate.

For example, $a=1$ gives $r_1=1.49229$ (the exact solution being $1.50068$) and $a=2$ gives $r_1=6.24783$ (the exact solution being $6.24911$